# javascript keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, navigation, keyboard

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to add a script to my site that will allow users to navigate to each page using the keyboard.  So far I haven't been able to get it to function at all.  Here's what I've got:

```
function addListener(element, type, response) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, response, false);
    }
    else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + type, response);
    }
}

addListener(window, "keypress", function(key) {
    // do this stuff when a key is pressed:

    key = key || window.event;
    var theKey = key.which || key.keyCode;

    switch (theKey) {
    // if they hit a
    case 65 :
        window.location.href = "/about.html";
        break;
    // if they press r
    case 82 :
        window.location.href = "/resources.html";
        break;
        // if they hit l
    case 76 :
        window.location.href = "/links.html";
        break;
    // if they press h
    case 72 :
        window.location.href = "/index.html";
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp) [Access Keys]? These have the advantage of working with the UI well for non-visual user-agents.